# How to insert CheckBoxList Checked Item to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a check box list, and I want to insert its Checked items to Database;
I used this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkBox_service.Items.Count; i++)
        {

            if (checkBox_service.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                strcheck += "" + checkBox_service.Items[i].ToString() + ",";
            }
        }
```

In Database it is displaying

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList
```

in CheckBox field instead of Selected item. All other fields are having correct data as per entered...
I couldn't find any error, please guide me...

Answer (score 1):

Using wrong toString Method. Either use `checkBox_service.Items[i].SelectedValue` or `checkBox_service.Items[i].SelectedItem.Text` or `checkBox_service.Items[i].SelectedItem.Value`

Answer (score 0):

Create a table , where you have a boolean . and store the values ​​true or false in the database .
true for checked and false for not checked

Comment: When you answering, check the tags first please. In SQL-server boolean type does not exists. In new versions you may use *BIT* type to replace an *BOOLEAN* type, but it is in the latest releases. His DBMS is sql-server-2008. It is just about to mark something checked or not checked. But his questions is how to insert checked items, not their state. So it should be or some item's ID or item's text.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ you can easily get all values of selected items and then join all selected items to one string:

```
var selectedValues = from i in checkBox_service.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                     where i.Selected
                     select i.Value;

var strcheck = String.Join(",", selectedValues);
```

Keep in mind - that will work with simple values (e.g. strings). If you bind your checkboxlist to some complex objects, then values will be properties which you defined as `DataValueFiled`. E.g. with this databinding

```
checkBox_service.DataSource = new[] {
    new Fruit { Id = 1, Name = "Apple" },
    new Fruit { Id = 2, Name = "Banana" },
    new Fruit { Id = 3, Name = "Peach" }
};

checkBox_service.DataTextField = "Name";
checkBox_service.DataValueField = "Id";
checkBox_service.DataBind();
```

if you select first and third items, result string will be `"1,3"`. If you need to get concatenated text, then select `Text` property instead of `Value` and result will be `"Apple,Peach"`.